# Why don't catch the requested file URI my defined Route in Laravel 5.7?

Tags: laravel, laravel-routing, laravel-5.7

I have this codes in my `routes/api.php` file:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:api'], function () {
  Route::prefix('photoalbum')->group(function() {
    Route::prefix('image')->group(function() {
      Route::post('download/{albumId}/{size}/{filename}',
                  'PhotoalbumImageController@download');
      // ...
    });
  });
});

Route::fallback('HomeContorller@index');
```

Now I try to open this URL:

```
http://myproject.test/api/photoalbum/image/download/1/xs/dog.jpg
```

...and I get the result from the `HomeController@index` function. The other routes working fine.

**UPDATE**

The `php artisan route:list` get the correct list of routes, contain this:

```
|        | POST     | api/photoalbum/image/download/{albumId}/{size}/{filename}      |      | App\Http\Controllers\PhotoalbumImageController@download          | api,auth:api,auth |
```

Additionally: the requested file isn't exists. The controller should be process and serve it.

Why don't catch the request my defined Route and send it to the `PhotoalbumImageController@download` function and how can I fix it?

Comment: Can you please check with `php artisan route:list` and show what is displayed ?

Comment: Thanks, I updated the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your defined route type is POST and you are trying to access that via GET.
changing your route to `Route::get` solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this, and use name for routes it is useful, and remember if the call is GET, POST, PUT, etc.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:api','prefix'=>'photoalbun/image'], function () {
Route::match(['post','get'],'/download/{albumId}/{size}/{filename}','PhotoalbumImageController@download')->name('api.photoalbun.image.download');
    });
```

To see all route you can use

```
php artisan route:list
```

Comment: Thanks, but @behnam's answer solved the problem. It was defined as ˙post` but actually it's a `get` request.